# How to align a two line nav-item vertically?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a nav menu with items that can have one or two lines.

[image]

They should have the same height and the text should be vertically centered. Oh and of course the whole box should be clickable not only the text.

I tried it but the only clickable area is the text.

```css
   

header .nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 66px;
}
header .nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}
header .nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
}
header .nav ul li a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1e1e1e;
  padding: 10px 32px;
  display: block;
}
header .nav ul li:hover {
  border: 1px solid #1e1e1e;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two Line<br>Nav Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: your css not full.

Comment: No, it's LESS. I'm sorry. Will add blown up css code in a second

Answer (score 1):

Okay here you go, Remove you whole CSS and paste this, This will do everything you have asked.

CSS

```
header .nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 66px;
}
header .nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}
header .nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
header .nav ul li a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1e1e1e;
  padding: 10px 32px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
}
header .nav ul li:hover {
  border: 1px solid #1e1e1e;
}
```

HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two Line<br>Nav Item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 </header>
```

The text is vertical and the whole box is clickable

Answer (score 0):

To make the entire box clickable, try inserting the whole `li` element in the `a` tag, like so:

`<a href="#"> <li>Two Line<br>Nav Item</li> </a>`

(Assuming it's your `li` that has a black border).